# How to convert a file with words on different newlines into a dictionary based on values each word has?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, newline, key-value

I am trying to convert a file, where every word is on a different newline, into a dictionary where the keys are the word sizes and values are the lists of words.

The first part of my code has removed the newline characters from the text file, and now I am trying to organize the dictionary based on the values a word has.

```
with open(dictionary_file, 'r') as file:
    wordlist = file.readlines()
    print([k.rstrip('\n') for k in wordlist])
    dictionary = {}
    for line in file:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        dictionary[int(key)] = val
    print(dictionary)
```

However, I keep getting the error that there aren't enough values to unpack, even though I'm sure I have already removed the newline characters from the original text file. Another error I get is that it will only print out the words in a dictionary without the newlines, however, they aren't organized by value. Any help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

```
(key, val) = line.split()
    ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're trying to use `line.split()`. All you need is the length of the word, so you can use the `len()` function. Also, you use `collections.defaultdict` to make this code shorter. Like this:

```
import collections


words = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip()
        words[len(word)].append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with open(dictionary_file, 'r') as file:
    dictionary = {}
    for line in file:
        val = line.strip().split()
        dictionary[len(val)] = val
    print(dictionary)
```